# Predeclaring a function in Python

Tags: python

I am studying myself Python. Why does the following code not work? Do I have to pre-declare the other function, before using it?

```
def f():
    g()
    

def g():
    f()


f()
```

The code should create a never ending cycle.

EDIT: Why does this code output nothing?

```
def f1():
    print("1")
    f2()
  
def f2():
    print("2")
    f1()


f1()
```

Comment: It's helpful to include specifically what "not work" means - this works perfectly until it hits the _recursion limit_, because it's infinitely recursive.

Comment: This will just raise `RecursionError`

Comment: I edited the initial question.

Comment: It _doesn't_ output nothing. It outputs alternating 1s and 2s, then a gigantic traceback when it hits the recursion limit.

Comment: The code in the edited part of my initial post outputs nothing. Maybe there is a mistake in an indent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the predeclaration the answer is no. since python look for the function at execution.

but this code will probably fail because of the recusion limit.

```py
def g():
    print("a")
    f()

def f():
    print("b")
    g()


f()
```

you will get:

```
a
b
a
b
....
a
b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
....
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in g
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Your code don't create an infinite loop but an infinite recursion.

EDIT:
To answer the problem for you edited code : typo
if y try to copy your code it fails because of indent but if you recode it completly it works just fine (until recursion limit)